# How to run T4 template in Blazor project on build

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, blazor, t4

I have a Blazor project with a T4 template I wrote for scaffolding some code automatically. It works great from within Visual Studio, but I have to modify & save the template to get it to run again (as documented and expected).

I also want to run the template when building the project, so instead of VS running the template, it has to be MSBuild. I went through a bunch of articles about the topic and it looks like I have to re-import the default targets, [as explained here](https://thomaslevesque.com/2017/11/13/transform-t4-templates-as-part-of-the-build-and-pass-variables-from-the-project/).

I added the following to the top of my .csproj file, and this is when things went south:

```
<Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> The TargetFramework value 'netstandard2.1' was not recognized. It may
> be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or
> TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified
> explicitly.   TestProject C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets    93

Full .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />
    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
        <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note the info from the article:

> Fortunately, there’s a workaround: you can import the default targets
> file explicitly, and import the text templating targets after that:

**Solution**

You should import those targets after `netstandard 2.1` node.

**In my side**, I use these:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
        
           <PropertyGroup>
               <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
               <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
           </PropertyGroup>
       
       
         <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />
         <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"/>
       
           <ItemGroup>
               <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1"/>
               <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build"
   Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
               <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer"
   Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
               <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0"/>
           </ItemGroup>
       
 </Project>
```

**Then**,

[image]

Comment: Oh yes! That did it. I didn't realize that the TargetFramework element had to be specified first. Makes sense in retrospect, but I know very little about MSBuild. Now is there any reason why your example has Microsoft.NET.Sdk and not Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web?

Comment: Oh, haha, it is a mistake made by me. It should be `<Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />`. I have updated my answer and you can check it.